# What are the libraries available to detect platforms/compilers at compile time based on C preprocessor macros?

Tags: cross-platform, c-preprocessor

I am writing some cross platform C++ libraries requiring platforms specific implementations. To compile a library for a specific platform/compiler/etc, one has to detected the platform/compiler in the first place at compile time and based on C preprocessor macros.

I found two libraries so far:

- [POSH](http://poshlib.hookatooka.com/poshlib)
- [Predef](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/)

**Are there any other ones ?** I am especially interested in the ones that can detect iOS/Android platforms, Clang compiler for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional searching, I have not found any new ones.